# Get html comment element as string with SimpleHTMLDomParser in PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing

From the official manual I know that I can get all the comments with the following code:

```
 // Find all comment (<!--...-->) blocks 
$es = $html->find('comment');
```

But this creates an array of comment nodes. I want to get the content of the comments as string. How could I do that?

I've tried with $es->plaintext, $es->innertext and $es->outertext.

Here is an example of what I want:

HTML:

```
...
<div id='a'>
<!-- Some text -->
</div>
...
```

PHP:

```
...
$content = $html->find('div[id=a]', 0)->find('comment', 0)->some_attr;
echo 'Content:'.$content;
```

Browser:

```
Content: Some text
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution!

When we load an html with SimpleHTMLDom,  the comments (scripts and others things) are removed from document and saved inside an array called 'noise'.

We can get a comment/script/etc searching an string pattern in the whole list of noises and there is a function to do that.

This is the solution:

```
$html->search_noise($subString);
```

So, in my own example, the solution can be:

```
1.- $comment = $html->search_noise('Some');
2.- $comment = $html->search_noise('text');
3.- $comment = $html->search_noise('me te');
4.- etc etc
```

The search_noise function returns the first noise that match the pattern, so, we have to be a little careful with the chosen sub-string.